# How to delete '#' symbols from a given file C

Tags: c

file1

```
:once:echo Hello # this is a comment
:once:echo 1
:once:echo 2
:once:echo 3
:once:echo 4
```

Consider the file above, If I wanted to print out each line one by one how would I remove the "# this is a comment" and ':once:'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char buf[100];
    char p;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file)) {
        if ((p = strchr(buf, '#')))
            *p = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buf);
    }
    fclose(file);


}
```

I think I can use strchr to remove the comments but unsure how to go about this.

I want the output to be this

```
$ gcc -Wall a.c
$ ./a.out file1
echo Hello
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
echo 4
```

Current output:

```
:once:echo Hello  # This is a comment

:once:echo 1

:once:echo 2

:once:echo 3

:once:echo 4
```

Unsure why the extra space is there. I think I have the right approach with the strchr just unsure how to use.

Comment: What is the current output of the code?

Comment: Edited the post to put it

Comment: You can find `:once:` at the start (`strncmp()` after checking length?) and skip it if found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `char p;` to `char *p;`, otherwise this is not going to work at all. If you're looking for `:once:` only at the start of a line, you can use `strncmp()` to check the first six characters, and offset the start of the string if necessary.

Also, since `fgets()` retains line break characters, you may as well add `\n` and `\0` when you encounter a `#` symbol, and then leave out the `\n` when printing each line. That way your output won't be filled with double line breaks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char buf[100];
    char *p;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file)) {
        if ((p = strchr(buf, '#'))) {
            *(p++) = '\n';
            *p = '\0';
        }
        printf("%s", buf + (strncmp(buf, ":once:", 6) == 0 ? 6 : 0));
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. I added a nested `for` inside of the `while`, to loop through `buf` and check for the **'#'** hash character. You should always be sure to check if the necessary file exists or not, instead of assuming that it does.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *file;
    if (!(file = fopen(argv[1], "r"))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "The specified file does not exist\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char buf[100];
    int x;
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file)) {
        for (x = 0; x < sizeof(buf); x++) {
            if (buf[x] == '#')
                buf[x] = '\0';
        }
        if (strncmp(buf, ":once:", 6) == 0)
            printf("%s\n", buf + 6);
        else
            printf("%s\n", buf);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```